# hidapi vs WIndows Driver API (hidsdi.h)

Tags: windows, usb, driver, hid, hidapi

I am trying to write an Winodws application that reads and writes a HID device. One way for me to do so is to use the [hidapi](https://github.com/libusb/hidapi). I also came across some [Winddows Driver API on HID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/_hid/).

It seems hidapi is quite straightforward to use in applications, but, are there also benefits to use Windows Driver API in applications, or when should I use them?

I also noticed that hidapi use `WriteFile()` to write device, while Windows Driver API has an API `HidD_SetOutputReport()`, I have a few questions:

- What are the pros and cons of using these APIs?
- Does either `WriteFile()` or `HidD_SetOutputReport()` support simultaneous writing to the same device from different applications?

Thanks!

I went through the online documents but cannot find answers.